# Is there a technique for re anti-aliasing an image to a different background color?

Tags: .net, asp.net, graphics, antialiasing

Is there a programmatic approach for drawing an anti-aliased image on a new background color / pattern that would re-anti-alias the image to the new background color?  Preferably accessible to a .Net program?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPF to create the new image and save it out to an image file.

Answer (score 0):

If an image has already been anti-aliased against a particular background colour then removing this anti-aliasing automatically will prove difficult in code - your best bet is to manually edit the image, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it in the general case. But if you limit your requirements a bit, it can be done.

I can tell you how to do it if we assume the anti-aliased image is of a solid color known to us, *and* we have the background as a separate file.

For example let's say the anti-aliased image consists of a word in some font, in black. And the background is arbitrary. Then, to "re-antialias" the image for another background, you need two steps:

1. Recover the original anti-aliased image, isolated from the background. To do this, perform this algorithm:

   `for_every_pixel {

       isolated_pixel_intensity = 1 - rgb_distance(mixed_pixel_rgb - background_pixel_rgb, foreground_solid_rgb)

   }

   // rgb_distance is implemented as Pythagora's Theorem in 3D.`
2. Now that you have the foreground image, simply blend it with your new background.

You'd have to write the code yourself. You can use `System.Drawing.Bitmap` as a basis since you're using .NET.

**Edit:** Disregard this. It can't actually work, because there are cases that are impossible to solve - namely, when the background image contains areas of the same color as the foreground.